# Node js to html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Как можно вывести переменную из Node.js в HTML?

Например:

```
const os = require("os" )
let un = userInfo. username
```

Нужно вывести un в HTML.

Comment: подробней можно? откуда userInfo? куда html выводить?

Comment: "в html" в html файл или в браузер?

Comment: Почитайте про шаблонизаторы - только такой ответ можно дать с такими вводными в вопросе...

Comment: Данные из node js в. браузер

Comment: UserInfo из модуля os хочу вывести в браузер

Answer (score 0):

Вот так попробуйте

```
const express = require('express');
const os = require("os" );
const app = express();

let un = os.userInfo().username;

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send(un);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

в браузере откройте localhost:3000